# Python. Excel Ввод и вывод

Tags: python, excel

Добрый день. Я почти абсолютный ночь в языке, но требуется решить одну задачу. Вроде бы и не сказать что сложно, но как ее реализовать я не понимаю. Работаю в Pycharm, xldr xlwt - загружены.

Есть файл Excel, в нем матрица 8 на 29, заполненная 0 и 1. Каждая строка это данные организации, каждый столбец - критерий, соответственно 0 или 1 - выполняется он или нет.

Нужно для каждой организации в отдельной ячейки высчитать оценку (но пока просто хотя бы просуммировать в ней эти 0 и 1), то есть что бы прога считала данные из таблицы, посчитала и вписала в конкретную ячейку.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, если подскажите как обработать таким образом хотя бы одну строку, буду очень благодарна.

[image: как выглядит сам файл]

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/excel_file.xlsx')
df['Evaluation'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
df.to_excel(r'/path/to/result.xlsx', index=False)
```